# What is the correct way to write a udev rule to stop a service under systemd

Tags: linux, udev, systemd

I'm running Arch Linux, and I have a udev rule which starts a service when a device is inserted. In this case, it dials a connection when a 3G modem is plugged in.

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SYMLINK=="gsmmodem", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="netcfg@wvdial.service"
```

However, if the device is removed, systemd won't stop the service, and hence when it is plugged in again, it won't start the service, since it's already running.

What I need is a matching udev rule which runs when the device is removed to stop the service.

## Update

Using the answer below, what I now have is the following udev rule

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SYMLINK=="gsmmodem", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="vodafone.service"
```

with the following service file (which was basically copied and pasted from the netcfg service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Netcfg networking service for Vodafone Dongle
Before=network.target
Wants=network.target
BindsTo=dev-gsmmodem.device
After=dev-gsmmodem.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/netcfg check-iface wvdial
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/netcfg down wvdial
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm using `netcfg-wvdial` from the AUR to do the dialing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem may be solved using systemd solely, by simply specifying that your service [Requires](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=) or, even better, [BindsTo](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#BindsTo=) the given device.

Quoting:

[*"If one of the other [required/bound to] units gets deactivated or its activation fails, this unit [service] will be deactivated"*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=)

You just need to edit your service file like the following.

```
[Unit]
<...>
BindsTo=<DEVICE UNIT HERE>.device
<...>
After=<DEVICE UNIT HERE>.device
```

Note: to get a list of all available device unit files use `systemctl list-units --all --full | grep ".device"`

Comment: Does this mean that I don't need the udev rule? I tried to do as you suggested, by creating a new service file to replace the netcfg @wvdial.service and including those two lines. It does seem to stop the service now, but it doesn't start it when the device is plugged in again.

Comment: @crazystick you still need the udev rule for starting the service, what I meant is you won't need to use udev to stop it.

Comment: Got it. Works very nicely with both the udev rule and the modified service file.

Comment: You can use `StopWhenUnneeded=true` instead `BindsTo` and `After`

Comment: @SergA by the time I answered this there was [a bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69989) preventing `StopWhenUnneeded=true` from working, but I believe it's been fixed for quite a while now.

Comment: @brunocoduta just saw this bug. `StopWhenUnneeded=true` works well on systemd 215.