# How do I connect a 3G dongle using systemd?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, systemd, 3g

At startup, `usb-modeswitch` automatically switches the dongle to modem mode and the device shows itself as `12d1:1506`. After this, a script should run, connecting to the Internet. I am not sure about using `/etc/rc.local` since Arch has moved to pure `systemd`. How to I express this dependency (run a script only after the device has switched) in `systemd` terms?

`udev` rules cannot run long scripts, and mine is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended approach would be to have `udev` start a `systemd` service, which itself depends on your device.

The service file should look something similar to the following:

`my.service` - to be placed in `/etc/systemd/system`

```
[Unit]
Description=<DESCRIPTION HERE>
BindsTo=<DEVICE UNIT HERE>.device
After=<DEVICE UNIT HERE>.device

[Service]
ExecStart=<CALL TO SCRIPT HERE>
```

Note: to get a list of the available device units use

```
list-units --all --full | grep ".device"
```

And the `udev` rule should be something like the following:

`90-my.rules` - to be placed in `/etc/udev/rules.d`

```
KERNEL=="tty*", ATTRS{serial}=="<DEVICE SERIAL HERE>", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="my.service"
```

Note: to get a list of the attributes of your specific device, including its serial number, use

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/tty*
```

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63232/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-a-udev-rule-to-stop-a-service-under-systemd/89882#89882), though fairly different, might also be of interest.